# raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace) ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available

Tags: python, windows, gtk, cx-freeze, gdk

I have a small program on python, using python 3.4 . However I cant manage to get it working into a .exe using Cx_freeze on windows.

I get the error :

```
\build\exe.win-amd64-3.4>lcp.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "LCP.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\__init__.py", line 118, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

When attempting to run the .exe using cmd as running it normally with double click I get just a screen that opens and crashes.

The program uses gi.repository and has this code at the beggining:

```
import  gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from    gi.repository   import  Gtk,Gdk
```

my setup.py is like this right now:

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import  gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from    gi.repository   import  Gtk,Gdk



build_exe_options = { "include_msvcr": True}

# Frozen executables made by build_exe need to have everything that GTK
# loads at runtime available under the root where the built .exe goes.

common_include_files = []


# On MSYS2's MINGW64/32 enrironments, the DLLs we want are in PATH.
# Typically this means /mingw64/bin/libwhatever.dll.  An alternative way
# of forming the list of required DLLs would be to parse the relevant
# .gir files (see below). However, libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll wouldn't be
# listed.

required_dll_search_paths = os.getenv("PATH", os.defpath).split(os.pathsep)
required_dlls = [
    'libgtk-3-0.dll',
    'libgdk-3-0.dll',
    'libepoxy-0.dll',
    'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
    'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
    'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
    'libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll',
    'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll',
    'libatk-1.0-0.dll',
]

for dll in required_dlls:
    dll_path = None
    for p in required_dll_search_paths:
        p = os.path.join(p, dll)
        if os.path.isfile(p):
            dll_path = p
            break
    assert dll_path is not None, \
        "Unable to locate {} in {}".format(
            dll,
            dll_search_path,
        )
    common_include_files.append((dll_path, dll))


# We need the .typelib files at runtime.
# The related .gir files are in $PREFIX/share/gir-1.0/$NS.gir,
# but those can be omitted at runtime.

required_gi_namespaces = [
    "Gtk-3.0",
    "Gdk-3.0",
    "cairo-1.0",
    "Pango-1.0",
    "GObject-2.0",
    "GLib-2.0",
    "Gio-2.0",
    "GdkPixbuf-2.0",
    "GModule-2.0",
    "Atk-1.0",
]


# Packages that need to be bundled go here.

common_packages = [
    "gi","gtk-3.0", "Gdk-3.0" # always seems to be needed
    # "cairo",   # Only needed (for foreign structs) if no "import cairo"s
]


ejecutable = Executable(
    script ="LCP.py",

    #compress = True,
    #copyDependenFile = True,
    #appendScriptToExe =True,
    #appendScriptToLibrary = True,
    #icon = "imagen"
    )


includes =['os','gi','gi.overrides']
packages = ['gi', 'os']

include_files= ['respuestasFrecuentes.txt']     #archivos extra q no sean .py


setup(
        name = 'Respuestas Frecuentes',
        author = 'Irina Marcano',
        version = '0.1.0',
        description = 'facilidad para modificar tus respuestas recientes',
        executables= [ejecutable],
        options = {"build_exe":{
            "includes": includes,
            "packages": packages,
            "optimize": 2,
            "include_files": include_files,
            #"include_msvcr": include_msvcr,
        } }
    )
```

That setup.py took me days to make as at the beggining it had trouble. So far not even copying the dll from the libraries on the folder works. Im stuck with that error on top and I have no idea what to do now . I am using windows 10 , on windows 8 it also wont work and give the same error as stated at the beggining. Opening the program on its .py works perfectly, opening even using python 3.6 works minus a few errors as its missing  gi and gtk.

to note that when using python setup.py build, I get this message:

```
    Missing modules:
? UserList imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? _winreg imported from platform
? ce imported from os
? gi.repository.Atk imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GLib imported from gi.overrides.Dee, gi.overrides.GObject, gi.overrides.Gio, pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GObject imported from gi.overrides.GExiv2, gi.overrides.Gedit, gi.overrides.Gtk, gi.overrides.Vips, pygtkcompat.generictreemodel, pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GUdev imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.Gdk imported from lcp__main__, pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GdkPixbuf imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GdkX11 imported from gi.overrides.Gdk
? gi.repository.Gio imported from gi.overrides.Ggit, pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GooCanvas imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.Gst imported from gi.overrides.GstPbutils, pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GstAudio imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GstBase imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GstController imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GstInterfaces imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GstPbutils imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.GstVideo imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.Gtk imported from lcp__main__, pygtkcompat.generictreemodel, pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.Pango imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.PangoCairo imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.Poppler imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.Vte imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.WebKit imported from pygtkcompat.pygtkcompat
? gi.repository.cairo imported from gi.overrides.Gdk
? grp imported from shutil, tarfile
? java.lang imported from platform
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, shutil, unittest.util
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from http.server, posixpath, shutil, tarfile, webbrowser
? termios imported from tty
? vms_lib imported from platform
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

I have no idea yet how to remove most of them as my program is only using gtk and gdk which I need gi to access to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and spent lots of my time on finding the solve.

1. add this section to your cx_freeze's setup.py that wrote above:

   ```
   for ns in required_gi_namespaces:
       subpath = "Lib\girepository-1.0\{}.typelib".format(ns)
       fullpath = os.path.join(sys.prefix, subpath)
       assert os.path.isfile(fullpath), (
           "Required file {} is missing" .format(
               fullpath,
       ))
       common_include_files.append((fullpath, subpath))
   ```
2. create a new environment variable named 'GI_TYPELIB_PATH' and add the copied gi_repository folder in your project \lib dir to it's value. or add this path dynamicly in runtime using  `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`